# Emulate new request in Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, structuremap, dbcontext

I have an MVC 4 application where I use StructureMap to manage my repositories and Entity framework DBContext.
like this:
 x.For().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use();

IDbContext is injected into repository by constructor injection.

Now, when I do unit tests, I use
var repository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance();
to get my Repository.
The problem is I get the same DBContext every time in a test.
But I want to test how it behaves in disconnected mode so I need new dbcontext to be created when i want.
Because unit tests does not have "Per request" scope, how can I emulate per request so I can get new DBContext when i need it in my tests.

Please help
thanks

Comment: That seems like a uninteresting thing to unit test to me. You should have an integration test that tests whether the DbContext is registered correctly, and in your unit tests you simply create the object graph manually. During unit tests the graph will we very shallow, since you'll mock everything but the class under test. So there's no need to reuse the same instance within the test, and there's no need to let the IoC container resolve an object graph. You shouldn't even use a IoC container in your tests.

Comment: I want to test how my repository behaves in disconnected mode by so i mean:
1. Load an entity wit its dependencies.
2. Edit that entity, add new dependencies or edit existing one
3. Try to update the entity.

I want to see that it executes updates on root entity and updates on updates on references, but and insert to a new entity.
Because in test I always have the dbcontext, all test runs well, but in mvc app, i will load an entity in one request, and update in another. That's two different db context.